# mail: unrecognized option '-S' | sending mail from linux server

Tags: linux, email, remote, mail-command

I am trying to run a bash to send emails from my linux server. I am using the following command:

`echo "This is the message body" | mail -s "This is the subject line" -a "From: <Sender>" -a "To: <recipient>" -S smtp="smtp.gmail.com:587" -S smtp-use-starttls -S ssl-verify=ignore -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user=$SMTP_USER -S smtp-auth-password=$SMTP_PASS <recipient_email_address>`

I am receiving the error: `mail: unrecognized option '-S'`

As far as I read, previously mailx was used but this error shouldn't occur with mail command. can you please help me where I am going wrong?

System Info: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1040-azure x86_64)

`mail --version` >> mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.7

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `mail --version`.

Comment: ... and also mention what Linux distribution and version you are using.

Comment: Does `man mail` show you the `-S` flag as an option? What does it tell you about it?

Comment: - Panki, mail --version >> mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.7
- Kusalananda, System Info: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1040-azure x86_64)
@roaima, actually no. just checked.. any idea how to work with SMTP in that case?

Answer (score 1):

The `-S` option to set a variable is recognised (only) by [Heirloom `mailx`](https://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html). You've got `mail` from [GNU mailutils](https://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html), which does not support this option.

If you need to set your SMTP values on the command line you will need to install Heirloom `mailx`. Otherwise look at getting your MTA (Mail Transport Agent) configured properly to do this all for you. For this simple case of forwarding, I would suggest you consider [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/) (configuration suggestions on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Msmtp), which include a recipe for sending through Gmail).